# Cannot find the origin of f5_cspm = 1234 cookie on website

Tags: php, wordpress, httpd.conf, f5

On one of the wordpress websites, I deactivated all plugins, tried searching on google to find the origin of this cookie (f5_cspm) but I am not able to understand how this cookie is generated. I modified the server configurations by referring the link - [Secure cookie with HttpOnly and Secure flag in Apache](https://geekflare.com/httponly-secure-cookie-apache/)

The version of the httpd server I am using is 2.2.15. The value of this cookie is "1234". A very strange value too. I would like to know if this a bogus cookie, and if not then I need to set the "httponly" and "secure" attributes for this cookie. On the wordpress admin panel, I see this same cookie being generated 3 times! Please help me understand if I can ignore this cookie.

Comment: It looks like this has something to do with a “BIG-IP Analytics” service provided by a company named F5. But we can’t tell you what in your WP setup might trigger it from the outside. If you deactivated all plugins already, I’d maybe check for embedded client-side script / multimedia players / social plugins etc. next.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying @CBroe. But I have found this cookie on non-wordpress websites such as PHP website which was built on Laravel framework and hence I realized that this cookie has nothing to do with wordpress. So if this cookie has something to do with "BIG-IP Analytics", but I have not subscribed to this Analytics, then why is it still appearing on website...cannot figure out why it is showing up...

Answer (score 1):

That is the analytics cookie from the AVR module on the F5 BIG-IP Local Traffic Manager, an application deliver controller that sits in front of web/app servers. If you do not control this infrastructure layer in front of your site, you cannot change the behaviors between clients and the proxy. Your provider might be able to assist, however.

Comment: Could you please send me some reference articles for same...I am having trouble understanding...